# Filling in columns

Tags: python, multiple-columns

I have the following data:

1)

```
1 1
1 3
1 5
2 1
2 2
```

What I need to do is to fill in the missing rows like this:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 1
2 2
```

After which I need to populate a new column so that the new rows have a zero and the old rows have a 1, like this:

```
1 1 1
1 2 0
1 3 1
1 4 0
1 5 1
2 1 1
2 2 1
```

After which I would have to transpose the last column into a row like this:

```
1,0,1,0,1,1,1
```

I am stuck at the first step, not knowing how to check for and fill the entries so I cannot really give you an example of my work... Thank you for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Columns of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,1,1,2,2], "y": [1,3,5,1,2]})

df["rep"]=np.where(df["y"].lt(df["y"].shift(-1)),df["y"].shift(-1).sub(df["y"]).sub(1), 0)

df=df.loc[df.index.repeat(df["rep"].add(1))]

df["y"]=df["y"].add(df.groupby(level=0)["y"].cumcount())

df["rep"]=df.groupby(level=0)["y"].cumcount().lt(1).astype(int)

df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

And the output you're looking for:

```py
>>> print(df["rep"].T.tolist())
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

>>> print(df)
   x  y  rep
0  1  1    1
1  1  2    0
2  1  3    1
3  1  4    0
4  1  5    1
5  2  1    1
6  2  2    1
```

Comment: Hi Gregor and thank you so much for your answer. Your code works great but when I try a large number of entries, what I get is an example below where I simply have ... instead of full entries. An example:                                                                                                        `x    y  rep
0        2    1    1
1        3    1    1
2        4    1    1
3        5    1    1
4        6    1    1
...    ...  ...  ...
37405  831  828    1
37406  832  828    1
37407  830  829    1
37408  832  829    1
37409  831  830    1

[37410 rows x 3 columns]`

Comment: Oh figured it out sorry, should do                                                `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 37410)`